# Ember: Is there any way to replace the ember input instead of html input after DOM insert?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ember.js

In my previous session, I have asked about how bind ember input value in html input box. Got the response as "Can't". So Is there any other way to solve this use case?

Like Need to insert a ember view instead of that html input in DOM after  that html input inserted?

I am giving there previous working demo here.

[PREVIOUS WORKING DEMO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29647389/how-to-bind-js-input-value-in-ember/29653236?noredirect=1#comment47494781_29653236)